# JPA Inheritance - I want to delete parent row with child rows how do I do it

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

Parent Class

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class OnlinePost {
    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(
            name = "onlinePost_sequence",
            sequenceName = "onlinePost_sequence",
            allocationSize = 1
    )
    @GeneratedValue(
            strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE,
            generator = "onlinePost_sequence"
    )
    private Long postId;
    // some other columns, getters and setters

}
```

Child Class

```
public class Post extends OnlinePost{
    private String image;
    private String title;
}
```

I want to delete the parent, then delete child element automatically

Comment: I don't quite understand - what is the parent and Child relationship in this case? If you have a Post instance, just delete it - all data associated with it (if it is an entity) will be deleted. So if it spans Post and OnlinePost tables, that includes the rows associated to it - automatically. Rows in the OnlinePost table are not onlinePost instances - if you try to read them, you will get back subclass (Post) instances where there are associated subclass data. Are you maybe trying to describe some other non-inheritance relationship between these classes?

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following. Instead of extending you can map the entity together like below

```
@Entity
public class OnlinePost {
    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(
            name = "onlinePost_sequence",
            sequenceName = "onlinePost_sequence",
            allocationSize = 1
    )
    @GeneratedValue(
            strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE,
            generator = "onlinePost_sequence"
    )
    private Long postId;
    // some other columns, getters and setters

    @OneToOne(cascade= CascadeType.DELETE)
    Post post;
}

public class Post{
    private String image;
    private String title;
}
```

By doing this when you delete parent . The child will be deleted automatically

Answer (score 0):

Create a child field in your parent class then map both class and apply cascade type delete in your relation to achieve the desired output example:

```
//for One to one:

@OneToOne(cascade= CascadeType.DELETE)
private Post post;
```